# Ordenamiento burbuja Alfabéticamente

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, estructuras

Tengo un problema con ordenar una cola en orden alfabético, realice un programa de tipo cola circular, ahora quiero que los elementos este ordenados alfabéticamente pero tengo este error:

Al ingresar todos los nombres (por ejemplo) y darle la opción 5 que es ordenarlos, al momento de usar la función pop para averiguar si fueron sacados de la forma correcta me dice cola vacía.

```
void ordenarCola(cola *miCola,int cantidad)
{
cola temp;

int i,j;
for (i=1;i<cantidad;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<cantidad;j++)
    {
        if(miCola[j].elem>miCola[j+1].elem)
        temp=miCola[j];
        miCola[j]=miCola[j+1];
        miCola[j+1]=temp;   
    }       
 }
}
```

Esta es la forma de la estructura y parte del main

```
 struct structColaC
 {
 char elem[Max][50];    
 int frente;
 int cantidadElementos;
 };

typedef struct structColaC cola;
int cantidad=0;
int main()
{
cola miCola;
int opcion;

char elem[50];
char *nombreRegreso;

crearCola(&miCola);
```

Esto va dentro de un do while para que meta tantos nombres como quiera

```
printf("Digite el nombre: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]",elem);
push(&miCola,elem);
printf("Se ha insertado %s en la cola\n",elem);
cantidad=cantidad+1;
```

Y la función push de la cola

```
int calcularUbicacion(cola *miCola)
{
return (miCola->frente+miCola->cantidadElementos)%Max;  
}
void push(cola *miCola,char elem[])
{
int ubicacion;

ubicacion=calcularUbicacion(miCola);
strcpy(miColaa"apuntando"elem[ubicacion],elem);

miCola"apuntando"cantidadElementos++;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una "*cola circular*" es un tipo de estructura de datos enlazada en que el último nodo de datos apunta al primero. Tú no tienes nada parecido a eso, por lo que no estás trabajando con una cola circular.

Sin embargo, parece que trabajas con un extraño búfer de datos que se rellena cíclicamente mediante un recuento de elementos que nunca parece decrecer, no se cuál esperas que sea el comportamiento de esta estructura de datos cuando `structColaC.cantidadElementos` supere `Max`.

Dejando de lado los errores conceptuales y de diseño, todo tu algoritmo de ordenación está mal porque confundes listas con elementos. El algoritmo de intercambio correcto no implica crear un objeto `structColaC` temporal si no un elemento temporal:

```
void ordenarCola(cola *miCola, int cantidad)
{
    char temp[50];

    for (int i = 0; i != cantidad - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j != cantidad; ++j)
        {
            if (strcmp(miCola->elem[i], miCola->elem[j]) < 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, miCola->elem[i]);
                strcpy(miCola->elem[i], miCola->elem[j]);
                strcpy(miCola->elem[j], temp);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Por otro lado tu algoritmo burbuja era incorrecto, la manera de comparar cadenas también (comparabas punteros, no cadenas) y al `if` le faltaban las llaves de apertura y cierre para encerrar tres instrucciones.

Comment: Que puede significar que `strcpy(temp, miCola[i]);` tenga este error "[Error] incompatible type for argument 2 of 'strcpy'" y gracias

Comment: Es una errata mía (que ahora corrijo), pero sería muy fácil de entender e identificar si tuvieses claro con qué tipo de datos estás trabajando (que parece que no es el caso).

Comment: Si, me parece que estoy implementando algo mal, desde el push tal vez o el pop, igual si puedo pasarte lo que llevo y me ayudes,si no estara bien, con algun libro que me recomiendes, de cualquier forma  has sido de gran ayuda Gracias

Comment: **Terminado** era un error de sueño    la linea `if (strcmp(miCola->elem[i], miCola->elem[j]) < 0)`  por  `if (strcmp(miCola->elem[i], miCola->elem[j]) > 0)`

Comment: @Ether No olvides de marcar esta respuesta como útil si es que solucionó tu problema.